# Razor @@ Escaping not working in Production Install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I'm stumped on a Razor parser issue, where things are working on my dev setup, but failing on my deployed site.

Specifically I have the following razor markup in a @section:

```
@section HtmlHeader 
{
    <style>
        @@media (max-width: 400px) 
        {
            #lnkHome { display: none; }
        }
    </style>       
}
```

This works fine on my local dev setup, but on the server I get:

**"@" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.**

Now I know I can easily fix this with:

```
@("@")media (max-width: 400px)
```

to escape the @@, but I want to understand why there is a difference in behavior.

To be clear - it appears the problem occurs only inside of a @section. If I have @@ outside of a section there's no problem in either versions. However, in the section the live site (running Server 2008 R2) it bonks.

What I checked:

- Same version of .NET 4.5 running on both machines
- All Razor and MVC files are Copy Local Deployed and Web Deployed
- Removed GAC'd MVC4 and Razor installations from Dev machines
- Dev Environment that works: Windows 8, live server: Windows 2008 R2

I'm assuming the 'correct' behavior is for @@ but it sure is not working on the live server.

Comment: What about enclosing it in an @html.Raw("...") block, to see if that works ?

Comment: 2nd thought, what host are you using locally and deployed? both IIS or are you using the VS2012 server perhaps ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the code is identical in both environments?  I ran into something similar once and it turned out to be a merge issue.

Comment: @Amy - yes. The site is Web Deployed and I can see it fail after I change the code from @("@") to @@. The @("@") works fine on the server, but not @@.

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly targeting different versions of Razor?  Same thing happened to me where I had targeted Version 2 locally and Version 1 was targeted on the server somehow.

Comment: Yes - as I said the app is Web Deploy installed and I've also wiped out the assemblies on the server and redeployed to ensure they are the right ones. Pages use many Razor 2 features so I'm sure it's 2.0 :-). But I agree it feels like different versions, but not sure what could be different given that web.config and bin folder are deployed.

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: have that in web.config. Still happening. I know that Razor/WebPages is definitely the new version because I'm using various Razor 2.0 features that are working properly - those would fail in 1.0.

Comment: That's a tough one.  Have you tried making a separate web page and just test that certain @@ issue?  Also if your out of ideas maybe remove WebPages 1 from Add/Remove programs.